# Finding area of three overlaying rasters in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have to find the area of three overlaying rasters which are DEM,LULC and Total Evapotranspiration at the same time so that I can find the landuse landcover area and evapotranspiration of land at a particular elevation.
I have used Tabulate area when just 2 of these overlaying rasters come but don't know which tool to use when three rasters are coming at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Combine tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm) to overlay multiple rasters at one time. Then you can perform whatever analyses you want on the resulting attribute table, depending on your needs; [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) would be a good place to start.

Comment: I combined them together into a raster.But how to findout the area of overlapping rasters in the same zone using Summary statistics tool.

Comment: How to find the overlaying area of the combined raster using Summary statistics tool.

Comment: @Greenman, depending on your needs, the attribute table of the combined raster might already give you your answer; you would only need to convert the "COUNT" field to whatever area measure you want. COUNT represents the number of cells that have that particular combination of input values. So, it depends on what your input cell size was.